# JSCH SFTP login using two factor authentication

Tags: java, authentication, sftp, jsch, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to connect to SFTP server using JSCH, server is configured for two factor authentication. But I am unable to find any option in JSCH to connect to the server using both password and keys at a time.
Help me if anyone knows how to connect programmatically to SFTP server using two factor authentication using either JSCH or any other Java package.

Comment: Just in case you don't find a solution - our SecureBlackbox ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-sftp.php ) supports multiple concurrent authentication mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of `addIdentity` methods in the [JSch](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html) class, which can be used to provide a key pair for public key authentication, and there is a [`setPassword` method in the Session](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setPassword%28byte%5B%5D%29) class.

I would simply use both and try to connect to the server.

The SSH protocol is made such that the server presents a set of authentication options in each step, and the client then selects of those one that it supports, and if I remember the code right, JSch simply does this.

Please report back if this actually worked, I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

As Paulo stated, you can use `addIdentity` to add your private key and also, in parallel, declare your password.

However this doesnt work with latest version of jsch (0.1.55).

I found [this](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/) fork of jsch which worked.
Same code, no need to change anything and i could finally connect to server using 2-factor authentication, password and publickey.